# Change y-axis tick values of a heatmap with R/Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I have the following R code:

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 12), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys")
p
```

[image]

1. How can I change the plot to see only the values 0, 1 and 2 on the y-axis but not the values -0.5, 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5 (something similar to the x-axis)
2. How can I add 10 to all my tick values on the y-axis in order to have 10, 11 and 12 instead of 0, 1 and 2.

Note that I am looking for a general concept as my matrix in reality is much bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I change the plot to see only the values 0, 1 and 2 on the y-axis but not the values -0.5, 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5 (something similar to the x-axis)

Add [`dtick = 1`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-dtick) to your `yaxis` in `layout`.

> How can I add 10 to all my tick values on the y-axis in order to have 10, 11 and 12 instead of 0, 1 and 2.

You can specify in [`ticktext`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-dtick) the text which is supposed to be shown for each tick. You also need to supply the `tickvals` and set `tickmode` to `array`.

### [image]

**Complete code**

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 12), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(dtick = 1, ticktext = 10:12, tickmode="array", tickvals = 0:2))
p
```